# schedule jobs on webserver [PHP, JAVA, C#, ...]

Tags: webserver, scheduled-tasks

i currently use PHP but i really need best answer that have , reliability, speed(no delay), so let me tell you my problem, i need to do some jobs on some specified time by "User" like sending email, so this "MAY" could happen 1000 times for different users in just one date and exact time , so i need a solution that best suits my need.

I heard about "Cron Jobs" and some websites , but i need some solution in which it does not need any other web sites to be run.

I need my entire web site to do scheduled jobs in "High Frequency" and "Reliably" all on my "Hosting server".

So Which technology , software, Technique, or even Web server changing (if there is no solution in php werb servers that can meet my needs) i need to learn/use ?

Answer (score 0):

after thinking a while i think the most reliable and great answer for my problem is to **Make a Local Application** that run on my laptop or desktop computer and make it run for 24 hours like a server and in that local application (which can be , C#, Java App, C++, even PHP app that run on your laptop or desktop and a "JS" script to repeatedly refresh you site to request some data) request a data or do a job in any intervals that you want with any frequency you desire , the only limitation you face , is your laptop or desktop hardware speed or internet connection.